# SharePoint Installation

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am using windows server 2012 and installing sharepoint 2016 but when I Run the setup I got this Messages.[image]

Comment: setup has given you the errors which are stopping the installation, what steps you have done so far to resolve those errors?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you have run the SharePoint 2016 installation file **before** running the SharePoint 2016 **Prerequisite** file!

So if you have **Internet Connection** on the server,  try to run the `Prerequisite file` to solve the listed issues and install the required prerequisites.

**Otherwise**, try to download and install the required prerequisites manually as mentioned at one of the below links

- [Install SharePoint 2016 Prerequisites offline/online](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2016-Prerequisit-17912ad2)
- [Download PreRequisites for SharePoint 2016 RTM for offline installation](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PreRequisites-for-7f719ff3)
- [SharePoint2016 Prerequisites](https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/complete-premise-sharepoint-2016-setup-guide-simple-easy-steps-troubleshooting/)

> **Note:** SharePoint 2016 is supported on Windows Server 2012

---

**Check also**

- [Windows Server AppFabric is not correctly configured in SharePoint 2016 / 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/06/14/windows-server-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configured-as-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites/)
- [Sharepoint 2016: failed to create the configuration database. An exception of type microsoft.Sharepoint.Upgrade.Spupgradeexception was thrown](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/05/21/sharepoint-2016-failed-to-create-the-configuration-database-an-exception-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spupgradeexception-was-thrown/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the step by step for SharePoint 2016 installation:

[Complete On-premise SharePoint 2016 Setup Guide with simple easy steps](https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/complete-premise-sharepoint-2016-setup-guide-simple-easy-steps-troubleshooting/)

And for the error, it needs to download the necessary componment, you could check the same error in the blog above, it resolved by PowerShell script.